# Function with TypeVar argument fails mypy when passing a Union of types

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I do not understand why the following code snippet fails mypy:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Union

T = TypeVar("T", int, str)

def f(x: T) -> T: 
    return x 

def r() -> Union[int, str]: 
    return 1 

f(r()) # an error is reported here
```

The specific error is: "Value of type variable "T" of "f" cannot be "int | str"  [type-var]"

With the TypeVar I am specifying that the function "f" may only accept a string or an integer. And the function "r" returns either a string or an integer. So why is this failing?

I tested this in mypy version 1.8.0 and Python 3.12.

Comment: This does seem to fix it:

`T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[int, str])`